# How toUppercase() one property of a list in kotlin with map?

Tags: dictionary, kotlin, transformation, uppercase

I don't understand why the uppercase is not applied when return the data?

```
val userList: LiveData<List<UserData>> = Transformations.map(userRepository.getUsers()) { data ->
    data.forEach {
        it.name.toUpperCase()
        Log.i("uppercase", it.name.toUpperCase()) //uppercase working here
    }
    Log.i("data", data.toString())  //uppercase not there
    return@map data
}
```

Comment: Strings are immutable. You need to assign `it.name.toUpperCase()` to `it.name`: `it.name = it.name.toUpperCase()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
val userList: LiveData<List<UserData>> = Transformations.map(userRepository.getUsers()) { data ->
    data.forEach {
        it.name = it.name.toUpperCase() //This is what you're missing, as explained by @forpas in the comment section.
        Log.i("uppercase", it.name.toUpperCase()) //uppercase working here
    }
    Log.i("data", data.toString())  //uppercase now there
    return@map data
}
```

**Credit goes to @forpas since he answered first but did not just add it as an answer.**